# Field created in spring component in not initialized with new keyword

Tags: spring, spring-boot, constructor, spring-cloud-stream

I have spring component class annotated with `@Component` and in it I have field ConcurrentHashMap map, which is init in constructor of component and used in spring stream listener:

```
@Component
public class FooService {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String> fooMap;


    public FooService () {
         fooMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @StreamListener(value = Sink.INPUT)
    private void handler(Foo foo) {
        fooMap.put(foo.id, foo.body);
    }
}
```

Listener handle messages sent by rest controller. Can you tell me why I always got there `fooMap.put(...)` NullPointerException because fooMap is null and not initialzied.

**EDIT:**

After @OlegZhurakousky answer I find out problem is with async method. When I add @Async on some method and add @EnableAsync I can't anymore use private modificator for my @StreamListener method. Do you have idea why and how to fix it? 
https://github.com/schwantner92/spring-cloud-stream-issue
Thanks.

Comment: Also, you might want to change the constructor name from StreamService to FooService.

Comment: @alexrolea I am sorry,  I just put my code here and rewrite names to Foo. In original code constructor has correct name. I fixed it also there.

Comment: Perhaps you can share your app on GH or some other place. What you describing is unreprodusable, hence something else is a miss

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky I find out where is problem. I got private method for \@StreamListener. When I change it to public it start working. But I need it private because I don't want that method will visible to other objects.

Comment: This has nothing to do with it being `private`, so something else we're not seeing there.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky I have no idea what it should be. I put my code to new project  to fastest find out what is problem and I got same issue

Comment: Well, until there s a way to reproduce the issue there is really no way of addressing it. hence my question about posting a sample project on GH or some other way of sharing the complete code

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky okay I uploaded code here: https://github.com/schwantner92/spring-cloud-stream-issue thank you for your time!

Comment: There is a lot going on there. What are you trying to accomplish? I mean what is your use case?
I mean you don't need half of what you have there. How about you simplify it to a single `@StreamListener` and send Message to it via Kafka topic. IN any event, I still can't reproduce it even after mimicing what you have there

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky InboundChannelAdapter s just for testing not for final usecase. I need do some logic with map in StreamListener when message is received,  but I can't because of map is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using @PostConstruct instead of constructor?

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    this.fooMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Denis Stephanov
When I say bare minimum, here is what I mean. So try this as a start, you'll see that the map is not null and start evolving your app from there.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    private final Map<String, String> map;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoRabbit174Application.class, args);
    }

    public DemoApplication() {
          this.map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    public void sink(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

}

Comment: Ok, I build app step by step from you code, and when I add \@EnableAsync and add some method annotated with \@Async, problem occured. It works only when I have \@StreamListener method as public.

Comment: Again, I am still trying to figure out what are you trying to accomplish. Your message handler method (the one annotated with StreamListener) is async by definition since it is invoked by a thread provided by task executor of a listener container. So I don't understand what/why are you bringing EnableAsync which is outside of scope of spring-cloud-stream.

Comment: Method annotated with Async will use for sending message to message broker

Comment: Check please this: https://github.com/schwantner92/spring-cloud-stream-issue/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kaviddiss/streamkafka/StreamKafkaApplication.java  I added to your code async method as I said. I not annotated StreamListener method with Async. I need use async for another one. But with this case I got null in listener when I print map

Comment: As I said, the usage of Async is neither necessary (in the scope of stream binders) nor it is in scope of spring-cloud-stream framework in general. 
Don't get me wrong, I am trying to help but I feel like you are trying to do something you shouldn't be doing. You asking me why your "design" is not working and I am questioning your design in the first place. So I need your use case to better understand what are you trying to accomplish to suggest the best possible solution.

Comment: I need send message by async method which will be called in some of our services. And when method will be called we don't want wait until method is done. For now method is just sending message into channel, but in future can be called some other slower task from that method. This is why I need annotate it as Async

Answer (score 0):

With Spring everything has to be injected.

You need to declare a `@Bean` for the `ConcurrentHashMap`, that will be injected in you `Component`. So create a `Configuration` class like:

```
@Configuration
public class FooMapConfiguration {

    @Bean("myFooMap")
    public ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String> myFooMap() {
        return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

}
```

Then modify your `Component`:

```
@Component
public class FooService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myFooMap")
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String> fooMap;

    public FooService () {         
    }

    @StreamListener(value = Sink.INPUT)
    private void handler(Foo foo) {
        fooMap.put(foo.id, foo.body); // <= No more NPE here
    }
}
```